# ImportError: cannot import name 'Document' from 'borb.pdf.document

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, borb

I have installed the **'borb'** library using `pip install borb` and after installation, I got the following message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: borb in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (2.0.25)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Requirement already satisfied: qrcode[pil]>=6.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (7.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=7.1.0 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (9.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.24.0 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=51.1.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (54.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (4.33.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-barcode>=0.13.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from borb) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from qrcode[pil]>=6.1->borb) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->borb) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->borb) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->borb) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->borb) (1.26.4)
```

Now, if I run the following code snippet I am getting an `ImportError`:

```
import typing  
from borb.pdf.document import Document  
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF  
from borb.toolkit.text.simple_text_extraction import SimpleTextExtraction  


def main():

    # variable to hold Document instance
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None  

    # this implementation of EventListener handles text-rendering instructions
    l: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()  

    # open the document, passing along the array of listeners
    with open("PDFs/1.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l])  
  
    # were we able to read the document?
    assert doc is not None  

    # print the text on page 0
    print(l.get_text(0))  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5400/405389204.py in <module>
      1 import typing
----> 2 from borb.pdf.document import Document
      3 from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF
      4 from borb.toolkit.text.simple_text_extraction import SimpleTextExtraction
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'Document' from 'borb.pdf.document' (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\borb\pdf\document\__init__.py)
```

Any inputs on how to resolve this...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please import `Document` Class from borb.pdf
usage: `from borb.pdf import Document`

Answer (score -1):

```
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
```

"Document" is a class from borb.pdf.document.document.py

Comment: This is actually not necessary and accomplishes the same task as in Akoffice's answer, as there is a `__init__.py` file in the `borb.pdf` directory which is loaded first and executes `from .document.document import Document`.